# Permission denied when trying to install sp_blitz on in the master database in Amazon RDS

Tags: sql-server, permissions, amazon-rds, sp-blitz

I am trying to install sp_blitz on AWS RDS SQL Server (14.0.3223.3) standard edition and getting following error:

Msg 262, Level 14, State 18, Procedure sp_Blitz, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 0]
CREATE PROCEDURE permission denied in database 'master'.
Msg 208, Level 16, State 6, Procedure sp_Blitz, Line 2 [Batch Start Line 3]
Invalid object name 'dbo.sp_Blitz'.

Please advise, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

That error message means you don't have enough permissions to install things in the master database.

That's okay: you can install sp_Blitz (and any other stored procs) in a user database instead, and they'll work fine there.

If you run into that same error in a user database (one you created), then you'll need to check with your sysadmins about your permissions.

Answer (score 3):

I would rather create a separate db and use it for installs like these. We create a db called 'dba' and then put all our required stuffs in that including the Ola Hellengren's maintenance solution.  This helps is segregating things.

We usually do not create anything on the system databases.